# Laravel stored procedure insert data to database not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**my controller**

```php
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'. time().'.'.$extension;
    $request->file('photo')->storeAs('public/employee/photo', $fileNameToStore);
    $input['photo'] = $fileNameToStore;
}
         
if ($request->hasFile('resume')) {
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalName ();
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('resume')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'. time().'.'.$extension;
    $request->file('resume')->storeAs('public/employee/resume', $fileNameToStore);
    $input['resume'] = $fileNameToStore;
}

$employee = DB::statement('call insertEmployes(?,?,?,?,?,?)', [implode(', ',$input)]);
```

**my error**

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: `call insertEmployes(er, rr@gmail.com, 3, 3, Resume (1)_1656479826.png, Resume (1)_1656479826.pdf,?,?,?,?,?)`)", "exception": "`Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException`",

**i am new in stored procedure in laravel.how to insert data in stored procedure**

**i am new in stored procedure in laravel.how to insert data in stored procedure****i am new in stored procedure in laravel.how to insert data in stored procedure**

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, the query being run from

```
DB::statement('call insertEmployes(?,?,?,?,?,?)', [implode(', ',$input)]);
```

is

```sql
call insertEmployes(er, rr@gmail.com, 3, 3, Resume (1)_1656479826.png, Resume (1)_1656479826.pdf,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You're only replacing 1 out of 6 `?` because you're using `implode`.

Try

```
DB::statement('call insertEmployes(?,?,?,?,?,?)', $input);
```

or

```
DB::statement('call insertEmployes(?,?,?,?,?,?)', array_values($input));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure("$Param1", "$param2",..)');
```

or

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?,..)',array($Param1,$param2));
```